# Apply style to specific lines of a listings environment

Tags: beamer, listings

I want to emphasize some lines in a listing environment by applying a special style on them (for example, a different background color).

All custom styling seem to be content-based. I would like to be able to do something like:

```
\lstinputlisting[emphlines={4},emphstyle=\color{red}]{sourcecode.f}
```

If it is not possible with the plain listings package, what do you suggest to get this effect?

My goal is to highlight different lines in different slides of a beamer presentation, so if there is a simple way to do this, I will be very thankful.

---

**Edit**: I came up with [this solution](http://gist.github.com/548097) after Ulrike's idea. I'm satisfied with the result, and the redundancy is bearable for my taste. It'd be very nice if someone more knowledgeable in TeX scripting suggests some improvements.

Comment: In case you're displaying line numbers, it's useful to add a `firstnumber=last` option, so that numbering sequentiality is preserved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way I know is to reinput the file with different firstline/lastline settings. Not difficult but a bit tedious:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,color}
\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[lastline=4,belowskip=0pt]{test-utf8.log}
\lstinputlisting[firstline=5,lastline=5,
   aboveskip=0pt,belowskip=0pt,backgroundcolor=\color{yellow}]{test-utf8.log}
\lstinputlisting[firstline=6,aboveskip=0pt]{test-utf8.log}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe this can be made less tedious by using TikZ' `foreach` macro. I'll give it a try, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to use the `semiverbatim` environment from `beamer`, see Section 3.13 (Verbatim Text) of the manual. The disadvantage of this method is that you don’t get highlighting.

In order to have all the functionality of the `listings` package, you could use its `fancyvrb` interface with `commandchars`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fancyvrb,listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \lstset{language=pascal,fancyvrb=true,basicstyle=\normalfont}
    \fvset{commandchars=\|[]}
    \begin{Verbatim}
|alert[for i:=maxint to 0 do]
begin
{ do nothing }
end;
    \end{Verbatim}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The symbols in `commandchars` are replacement characters for `\`, `{` and `}`, properly escaped with backslashes.

I don’t know however how to get overlay specifications (like `<1>`) to work.

Comment: I didn't know about semiverbatim. I'll take a look to the manual, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could save some arguments in your \emphline-command if you let LaTeX do some of calculations. linerange doesn't seem to like numexpr, but lastline and firstline works fine.  E.g in your example you could use

```
\newcommand{\emphline}[2]{%                                                    
 \lstinputlisting[lastline=\the\numexpr#1-1\relax]{#2}            
 \lstinputlisting[linerange={#1}-{#1},style=h]{#2}                            
 \lstinputlisting[firstline=\the\numexpr#1+1\relax]{#2}                       
}
```

and then

```
 \only<1> {\emphline{6} {potencia.f95}}
```

Comment: I didn't know about `\numexpr` either. This opens a world of possibilities!