# References to specific lines in program source code

Tags: cross-referencing, source, minted

How do I make references to specific lines in program source code (e.g. Python)? For example, I want to say:

> In lines 22-30, the algorithm is implemented...

If I changed the Python source code, "lines 22-30" will automatically change to reflect the new line numbers.

**EDIT:**
I'm using `minted`

Comment: `minted` uses the `fancyvrb` environment, but doesn't seem to support the `commandchars` option: this is a problem here :-( Perhaps Konrad can help out, as he actually writes `minted`.

Comment: Related (for listings): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2228/apply-style-to-specific-lines-of-a-listings-environment

Answer (score 3):

I don't use `minted`, but here's how I would do it for `fancyvrb`, which `minted` uses internally. Here, I define new command `\VerbLabel{linex}{a $ a}` which assigns the label `linex` to the source code line `a $ a`.

It's written using expl3, so see the source3 documentation for explanation for any of the commands that don't make sense. In brief: `prop` in expl3 is a ‘property list’ datatype that holds pair-value data. `\prop_gput` is the allocator, `\prop_if_in` tests for the existence of a key, and `\prop_get_gdel` is an accessor function that also deletes the entry afterwards.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,fancyvrb}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_gput:Nnn {Nxn}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_get_gdel:NnN {NxN}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_if_in:NnT {NxT}

\prop_new:N \g_verb_label_prop
\newcommand \VerbLabel [2] {
  \prop_gput:Nxn \g_verb_label_prop { \tl_to_str:n {#2} } {#1}
}
\renewcommand \FancyVerbFormatLine [1] {
  #1
  \prop_if_in:NxT \g_verb_label_prop { \tl_to_str:n {#1} }
  {
    \prop_get_gdel:NxN \g_verb_label_prop { \tl_to_str:n {#1} } \l_tmpa_tl
    \label {verbline:\l_tmpa_tl}
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\VerbLabel{linex}{a $ a}
\VerbLabel{liney}{c & c}

See lines \ref{verbline:linex}--\ref{verbline:liney}

\begin{Verbatim}[numbers=left]
1 _ 1
a $ a
b # b
c & c
9 ^ 9
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

There is a bug in this code which means it doesn't work for lines that contain the `#` char, but that's not an unsolvable problem.

Answer (score 1):

If one is willing to use a really simple bash script with the `grep` command it is really easy to get the linenumber of a specific part of the code, pass that number to a `\def` declaration and use it in your latex file.

Here is a link to the "`grep` and `cut`" combination answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21412398/7722668

The script would look something like that for python sourcecode files

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -n "some code of that line" /path/to/sourcecode.py | cut -d : -f 1 > linenum
read num < linenum
echo "\def\numoftheline{$num}" > linenumbers.tex

grep -n "code of some other line" /path/to/sourcecode.py | cut -d : -f 1 > linenum
read num < linenum
echo "\def\numofotherline{$num}" >> linenumbers.tex
```

If the content of the line is unique in the sourcecodefile it is easy to get that with `grep` if not, either use a line that is really close and adjust `num` by

```
num=$((num + 1))
```

before using the `echo` part.

Here is where I got that from: https://askubuntu.com/a/385531

Make sure to use `>>` in every `echo` command after the first one to append the line. `grep` on the otherhand is supposed to overwrite the file linenum every time.
If the lines above where 12 and 20 the file linenumbers.tex should look like

```
\def\numoftheline{12}
\def\numofotherline{20}
```

and after including

```
\input{linenumbers}
```

in the preamble one can use those commands for references and which might be more important in the `\inputminted` line selcetion:

```
\inputminted[firstline=\numoftheline,lastline=\numofotherline]{...
```

In most cases this works fine even when changes are made to the sourcecode.

To be safe one could check if `grep` found anything and give a warning/error if it didn't to avoid stuff like

```
\def\numofline{}
```

I know that this is a bit complicated, but it works and saved me a lot of time. I recommend keeping that script in the same folder as the `.tex` file(s) and using absolute paths for `grep`.